# python converting number into dollar format

Tags: python, csv, formatting

I'm importing a csv file and one of the prices is missing a zero.

**Desired output:** 12.10

**Current output:** 12.1

How would i enforce the zero to be contained in my data?

What i have done so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import sys
import argparse

#parsing command line options
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='desc', description=__doc__)
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', help='Input file', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default=sys.stdin)
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', help='Output file', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('w'), default=sys.stdout)
args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
inf, outf = args.input, args.output
outf = csv.writer(outf)

print 'Loading %s file into memory' % inf.name
data = []
tmp = 0.00
for i, line in enumerate(csv.reader(inf)):
    if i == 0:
        outf.writerow(line)
        continue
    price = line[4]
    price = price.replace('.', '')
    # print price
    if (price < 100):
        tmp = price
        tmp = tmp * 10
        print tmp
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Format](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec) your float as a string with 2 decimals:

```
>>> '{:.2f}'.format(12.1)
'12.10'
```

PS: you don't need to use the heavy `enumerate` function to skip the header of your `csv` file and rewrite it as such in the output. You can simply write the first line directly:

```
csvin = csv.reader(inf)
outf.writerow(csvin.next())  # header line 1
for line in csvin:  # iterator goes on from line 2
    price = line[4]
    #...
```

Comment: Is it possible to save that variable with 2 decimal places? Everytime i open it in a csv program like libreoffice the last 0 disappears.

Comment: If you open your csv generated file with Excel or LibreOffice, they will interpret your file and trailing zeros will disappear in the spreadsheet. If you want to keep the trailing zeros, you should directly generate an excel file or an odf document

Answer (score 3):

Two options:

1. Use a type where decimal places matter, such as [`decimal.Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html).
2. Ignore it for now, and on output use a format that specifies two decimal places such as `%.2f`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
print tmp
```

try

```
print '{0:.2f}'.format(tmp)
```

This forces the float to be formatted with two decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> price=12.10
>>> price
12.1
>>> print('{0:.2f}'.format(price))
12.10
```

Comment: This gives me the following error: `ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'`

Comment: `if (price < 100):` you're trying to compare a string with an int object?
convert it to a `float()` or `int()` first, that's why you're getting an error.